# Rollup: How to add Fonts as a part of Library Build

Tags: rollup, rollup-plugin-postcss

I'm creating a Javascript UI Library where I want to use Roboto Font as a part of Library. I have used "rollup-plugin-url" but it is not working.

Comment: Did you got a chance to fix ?. I need help on same

Comment: @Sam I install font using webpack in app where i am using my library.